# k-mean clustering minimize L1 distance

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces, median, clustering

[k-mean clustering minimize L1 norm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yTIl.png)

In k-mean clustering, if I want to minimize the L1 distance from any point to cluster center, the error function and derivative is shown above.
However, according to text book, "**Thus, if we solve for cp , we find that cp = median(x ∈ Cp)**" Why median is the solution?

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Answer (score 2):

The median is the solution because your error is just the sum of the signs (how many higher, how many lower).  The median has half the points higher, half the points lower, so that this error vanishes.

Comment: Appreciated if anyone can give an intuitive example

Comment: Can't you make your own example?